# pandas group by day or week or month

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm a pandas beginner.

I have the following data:

```
a = [
    {"content": '1', "time": '2020-01-01'}, {"content": '4', "time": '2020-01-01'},
    {"content": '2', "time": '2020-01-02'},
    {"content": '3', "time": '2020-02-01'}, {"content": '4', "time": '2020-02-02'},
    {"content": '5', "time": '2020-03-01'}, {"content": '6', "time": '2020-03-02'}
]
```

And I want:

```
2020-01: [{"content": '1', "time": '2020-01-01'},{"content": '4', "time": '2020-01-01'},
     {"content": '2', "time": '2020-01-02'},]

2020-02: [{"content": '3', "time": '2020-02-01'}, {"content": '4', "time": '2020-02-02'},]

2020-03: [{"content": '5', "time": '2020-03-01'}, {"content": '6', "time": '2020-03-02'}]
```

Comment: What is structure of final data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First convert list of dictionaries to `DataFrame`, then get `YY-MM` format of datetimes:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
g = pd.to_datetime(df['time']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
```

And in dict comprehension create dictionary of lists:

```
d1 = {k: v.to_dict('r') for k, v in df.groupby(g)}
```

Another solution if performance is important: with [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for x in a:
    d[x['time'][:7]].append(x)
d = dict(d)
```

Comment: Sorry, ask a little question ，why not use Series?

Comment: @xin.chen - It is possible, but then is necessary extract `date`s for processing, so if use `DataFrame` it create new column filled by times.

Comment: @ansev - yop, it is reason why added non pandas solution